# Applying Propeller and Wing forces to a MultiBodyPlant in Drake Part 2

Tags: python, c++, drake

I declared the output port as suggested in the previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120901/applying-propeller-and-wing-forces-to-a-multibodyplant-in-drake/72121171#72121171)
using `lambda: AbstractValue.Make([ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce() for i in range(N_props + N_wings)]` and that resolved the previous error related to `DeclareAbstractOutputPort`.

The new class is below:

```
    def __init__(self, N_props, N_wings):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self.DeclareAbstractInputPort("propeller_force",
            AbstractValue.Make([ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce(), ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce(), 
            ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce(), ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce()]) )
        self.DeclareAbstractInputPort("wing_force",
            AbstractValue.Make(ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce()) )
        self.DeclareAbstractOutputPort("spatial_forces", 
            lambda: AbstractValue.Make([ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce() for i in range(N_props + N_wings)]),
            self.OutputForces)

    def OutputForces(self, context, output):
        propeller_force = self.EvalVectorInput(context, 0)[0]
        wing_force = self.EvalVectorInput(context, 1)[0]

        print(propeller_force)
        print(wing_force)
        
        output.set_value([propeller_force, wing_force])
        print(output)
```

However, now I am getting this error when I attempt to connect the propeller "spatial_forces" output to the force concatinator.

RuntimeError: DiagramBuilder::Connect: Mismatched value types while connecting output port spatial_force of System drake/multibody/Wing@00000000044be370 (type std::vectordrake::multibody::ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce<double,std::allocatordrake::multibody::ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce<double>>) to input port wing_force of System **main**.SpatialForceConcatinator@0000000004491390 (type drake::multibody::ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce)

I believe this is due to the fact that I have 4 propeller forces coming out of the `Propeller` system, which has output of type `std::vector<drake::multibody::ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce<double>` while it looks like the type for the "propeller force" input port of the `SpatialForceConcatinator` is of type `drake::multibody::ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce<double>`

I have found another stack overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271126/applying-an-external-force-to-an-object-in-pydrake) where someone ran into the same error and they mentioned using the `VectorExternallyAppliedSpatialForced()` instead of `ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce()` when declaring the input port.

However when I try to import this class using `from pydrake.all import VectorExternallyAppliedSpatialForced` the import fails. And I do not see any mention of this class in the Drake documention.

Is this class still implemented in Drake? If not, is there another way to resolve the above error? I tried passing a list of forces to AbstractValue.Make() like so `self.DeclareAbstractInputPort("propeller_force", AbstractValue.Make([ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce(), ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce(),  ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce(), ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce()]) )`
but this did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to replace

```
        self.DeclareAbstractInputPort("wing_force",
            AbstractValue.Make(ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce()) )
```

with

```
        self.DeclareAbstractInputPort("wing_force",
            AbstractValue.Make([ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce()]) )
```

Your line with `output.set_value(...)` also looks suspicious to me.  `[list1, list2]` creates a list of lists, not one list of forces.  Perhaps you want `list1+list2`, or one of many ways to concatenate lists in python.