# How to add instantaneous force onto drake ball

Tags: robotics, drake

I'm working on a juggling robot iiwa, and am looking to add disturbances onto the ball every now and then to see how well the controller works. Is there an easy way to add a force/disturbance (e.g. wind) onto the ball?

If it's helpful I'm making the ball using a sdf file.

Answer (score 1):

[`MultibodyPlant`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html) has an `applied_spatial_force` input port to facilitate exactly this type of application. There are a number of relevant posts:

[Applying an external force to an object in pydrake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271126/applying-an-external-force-to-an-object-in-pydrake)

[Applying Propeller and Wing forces to a MultiBodyPlant in Drake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120901/applying-propeller-and-wing-forces-to-a-multibodyplant-in-drake)